# How do I find a table of certain class with jquery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I select just a table with class d with jquery selectors.  For some reason this code won't work properly...

```
var dTableTags = $(".d table");
```

example table would be...

```
<table id="thetable" class="d">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Column 1 header</th><th>Column 2 header</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Column 1 data</td><td>Column 2 data</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Honestly, there was some guessing involved.  In my mind I was thinking select all elements of class d, and then the tables associated from that list.  :\

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your selector is wrong; try `$("table.d")` instead.

The [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) does not explain this directly, it defers to the [W3C CSS selector documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html) which is a lot more comprehensive.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm in the process of learning jQuery and figuring selectors out.  I had figured out how to get th/td/tr of class d, but not for tables.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to search for **table** that is inside **class  d**
Which is wrong ..

Change your selector to this

```
$("table.d");   // Because the table has the class d
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an ID property/attribute set on the element, why are you selecting by class, anyways?  Selecting by ID is much better if you're trying to select something in a distinct fashion.  CSS classes can be shared, but the ID property, not so much.

Thus, your selector should be `$('#thetable')`

Anything else is superfluous really.